# Error : DEP0500 : The folder "...\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. Access to the path 'resources.pri' is denied

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8, .net-4.5, access-denied

I get this error a lot, when I try to debug my WinRT app on my local machine:

```
Error : DEP0500 : The folder "C:\Users\akku\VS2012Projects\ProjectName\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. 
Access to the path 'resources.pri' is denied.
```

The only thing that fixes it is restarting Windows 8. Googled around a bit and wondered that there was no solution to be found.

After some more testing I realized that this only happens when running or debugging the solution. The problem always seems to be that the AppX folder of the previous run could not be deleted. Maybe the debugger or the Visual Studio process that executed the last application run doesn't stop accessing some resources here?

*A quick hack I just used is to create a second Release and Debug-Configuration from the configuration manager. When the problem arises I can switch to another configuration, and the problem is solved temporarily.* I still would like a real working answer on how to circumvent this problem with a proper solution.

Has anyone experienced this and found a *better* fix?

Comment: Were you running this in a virtualized environment, especially Parallels? See this thread: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=267785

Comment: Please put this as an answer, of course I didn't leave my Macbook to program for Win8. This is the correct answer, so I'll accept it as such if you put as such. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I'm working on a Mac with Parallels Desktop and a virtualized Windows 8. As Ryan Joy pointed out in the comment under my question, a workaround can be found on the [Parallels Forums](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=267785).

"The .pri files are being locked because of the feature that shares guest applications with the host OS. As a workaround, I disabled the app sharing feature. I suggest you try this."

Comment: I encountered a similar behavior with Windows 8 and VMWare Fusion. Some files where locked by VMWare e.g. the VMWare Tools. Found out via Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and also 'fixed' by stopping and starting the VMWare Tools Service (http://ict-freak.nl/2009/05/05/restart-vmware-tools-on-all-windows-vms/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Live Share` extension, disable it and try to debug.